# CMS and Displaying custom 404 page

Tags: php, content-management-system

This is just a random question. I've heard of a few CMS making it easily manageable to where the root site can display a 404 page if the admin tells it to display it instead of the website just in case the user wants to put the site down for maintenance. I was just trying to seeif I could understand how this sort of task is accomplished.

Comment: What CMS?  It's hard to help you without knowing the details of your implementation.  It is quite simple to return a 404 status code with `header()`, and then some content.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean with manageable. Basically such features often just use Apaches `ErrorDocument` directive, or happen to be a by-product of the `RewriteRule` catch-all.

Comment: I don't know which one I've just heard of them doing it. I"m trying to work it into my php mysql cms.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($down_flag === true) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    include('404.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: istead of saying the page is not found when your site is disabled, perhaps you would want to show a maintainance.php and do no 404 error instead. you don't want to give the user the impression that their address is wrong.

Comment: [503 Service Unavailable](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.5.4) seems a good status code for this case.